# how to execute code 3 seconds later once executed in a infinite loop

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am making a game using html canvas in which i want to check for certain condition every time in animate loop and if that condition become true once then I don't want to check for next 3 seconds and after 3 seconds i want to check again. Like

```
function animate(){
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
  if (checking something){
    if this if statement gets executed then don't check this if statement for next 3 seconds 
  }
```

This might sound bit confusing but is there anyway to do this.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to add a flag - another variable that you can use to check if an operation should be done, and another function that'll toggle the flag after a certain amount of time.

```
// THE CHECKING FLAG
let shouldCheckCondition = true;

function animate(){
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
  
  // CHECK THE FLAG FIRST, IF SHOULD NOT CHECK, EXIT THE FUNCTION
  if (!shouldCheckCondition) return;

  if (condition){
    // DISABLE THE CHECKING FLAG SO YOU SKIP THE SUBSEQUENT CHECKS
    shouldCheckCondition = false;

    // DO SOMETHING WHEN CONDITION IS MET AND CHECKING SHOULD BE DONE

    // ENABLE THE CHECKING FLAG AFTER 3 second
    setTimeout(() => { shouldCheckCondition = true; }, 3000);
  }
```

Comment: if im not wrong animate is called continuiously... so there will be a setTimeout set continiously every time the loop runs which will eventually cause the condition to be always true

Comment: Yes, that's why the condition statement in the if clause was changed to check for the first condition and the value of flag. The moment the if clause condition is met, the flag's value is changed so subsequenct calls of the animate function won't trigger the code block in the if statement. So the animate function can be executed as many times as it needs in the next 3 seconds but not run the code inside the if statement because the flag is still set to false

Comment: @Amats man thank you very much i never it would be this simple and i was like totally forget about booleans

Comment: No problem, Dhanesh

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it inline within another method, setInterval might not help.

You can just make a note of the last time you did that check (eg. system time in milliseconds) and then make sure that it is more than 3000ms after that when you next do the check.

```
date.valueOf(); //An existing date object to milliseconds format
(new Date()).valueOf(); //current time in ms
```

You can have two `var`s `lastCheckedTime` and `currentTime`.

Answer (score 0):

`requestAnimationFrame` tries to run on the next frame, not after three seconds. So don't use `requestAnimationFrame`  if you want three seconds.

```
function animate(){
    if (checking something){
        setTimeout(animate, 3000);
    } else {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
}
```